# How to know when a borrow ends

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

I wrote this for simple input parsing:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut line = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut line)
        .expect("Cannot read line.");

    let parts = line.split_whitespace();

    for p in parts {
        println!("{}", p);
    }

    line.clear();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut line)
        .expect("Cannot read line.");

}
```

The above code creates a `String` object, reads a line into it, splits it by whitespace and prints he output. Then it tries to do the same using the same `String` object. On compilation I get error:

```
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
9  |     let parts = line.split_whitespace();
   |                 ---- immutable borrow occurs here
...
15 |     line.clear();
   |     ^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
19 | }
   | - immutable borrow ends here
```

As `String` is [owned by an iterator](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/the-best-practice-to-solve-error-e0502/9856). The solution is described as:

```
let parts: Vec<String> = line.split_whitespace()
    .map(|s| String::from(s))
    .collect();
```

I have few questions here:

1. I have already consumed the iterator by calling for each on it. Its borrow should have ended.
2. How do I know lifetimes of borrow from function definitions?
3. If a function is borrowing an object how do I know its releasing it? e.g. in solution using `collect()` releases the borrow.

I think I am missing an important concept here.

Comment: Please only post [one question per question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829), please.

Comment: These are related questions related to same concept, so posting three separate questions wouldn't be fruitful.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that you bind the result of `line.split_whitespace()` to a name (`parts`). If you write this instead:

```
io::stdin().read_line(&mut line)
    .expect("Cannot read line.");

for p in line.split_whitespace() {   // <-- pass directly into loop
    println!("{}", p);
}

line.clear();
io::stdin().read_line(&mut line)
    .expect("Cannot read line.");
```

That way it just works. Another possibility is to artificially restrict the lifetimes of `parts`, like so:

```
io::stdin().read_line(&mut line)
    .expect("Cannot read line.");

{
    let parts = line.split_whitespace();

    for p in parts {
        println!("{}", p);
    }
}

line.clear();
io::stdin().read_line(&mut line)
    .expect("Cannot read line.");
```

This also works.

---

**So why is that?** This is due to how the compiler currently works, often called "lexical borrows". The problem here is that each non-temporary value which contains a borrow will be "alive" until the end of its scope.

In your case: since you assign the result of `split_whitespace()` (which borrows the string) to `parts`, the borrow is "alive" until the end of scope of `parts`. **Not** until the end of life of `parts`.

In the first version in this answer, we don't bind a name to the value, thus the result of `split_whitespace()` is only a temporary and the borrow doesn't extend out the the whole scope. That's also why your `collect()` example works: not because of `collect()`, but because there is never a name bound to something borrowing the string. In my second version, we just restrict the scope.

Note, that this is a known shortcoming of the compiler. You are right, the compiler just doesn't see it.